# Can size of android database effects battery efficiency of the device?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, battery, android-sqlite

Irrespective of functionality, can simply the size the database directly effects the efficiency of the device? I read Opening and Closing database is an expensive task, so is this expense depends on the size of the database?

Answer (score 1):

The size of the database has *no* effect on the time needed to open it.
A big database becomes expensive only when you are actually accessing more data.

If you think that your app opens/closes the database too often, you should try to keep a connection around. This will trade off the additional effort against more memory use.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. The only problem is that you don't want to do premature optimization.

The size itself has a very, very, very minor effect on power usage, but accessing it would. It would be more of "how often do you read/write to the db". If it's once per app, then it shouldn't be bad on a moderate-sized db (moderate in the sense of a mobile device / maybe a few hundred entries). If it's often, then you should consider other options like if you can do a read cache in RAM

Comment: SO i can conclude Database size big/small doesn't matter to battery efficiency. Database size may be 100mb or 100kb, if opening and closing and functionality remains same - Efficiency should be same.